# Downvote's hunter

Tags: support, downvotes

I have a strange feeling since this morning... Someone's hunting my questions and answers and downvote each one.

I have 11 Q/A downvoted until now. If these Q/A are incorrect or don't help, that's ok, but here, it's continuously:

[image: screenshot of reputation wall]

Is there a way to fix it? Not to know who he is, and not to revenge but.. What can I do?

Comment: Nothing - if it's serial downvoting the system will correct for it.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of the above, because the system would have normally taken care of this. However, when looking into it I saw that these votes were cast by someone's sock puppet, so I deleted that account. You should see these votes be lifted momentarily, and the person behind that sock puppet has been dealt with.

Comment: Thank you @BradLarson. And also for the original post which gives me precisions about the system.